# no permission to see this field in strapi

Tags: strapi

I am unable to enter data to fields which I have created in user collection type in strapi.

I wanted to create extra fields in user collection in strapi so I created some extra fields from builder , but when trying to enter data , the newly created fields are not editable .

Comment: I got this "no permissions to see this field" after exporting some json at Settings -> Interface for a field that I had just added. The fun part is that I had access to that field minutes before - I could edit it. I fixed this by restarting the server (was not enough) and then doing log out and then log in. A bit weird.

Comment: For me restarting the server solved the issue!

Answer (score 11):

This issue generally occurs when new fields are added to existing content types.

In my case,
Simply signing out and logging in back in with your Admin account solves the issue. This will reset the permission issue for newly created fields.

Comment: This worked nicely.

Answer (score 7):

You can try following ways, and check if any one of them works -

**Method 1**

there can always be an issue with Strapi server,

- I restarted the server manually and it is fixed.

**Method 2**

your user might not have permission to view that field.
you can change permission of a user by -

**step 1** - Login to your strapi cms with Admin account and check if you are able to edit that field(the one with no permission), if so then continue with following steps, else this method wont work for you.

**setp 2** - click on settings in left panel , select the user , from the list select the user that you want to change permission with, give read write , and other permissions you want to give.

re-login with your account from which you were facing the problem, it should work now

**Method 3**

There might be a sync issue with your DB, sometimes your data is not synced with your DB, try deleting the field and re creating it.

I hope one of this solves your issue

Comment: Method 3 worked for me with Strapi 4.5.6 - I only changed a field name of a collection content type and re-deployed to heroku -> works.

Answer (score 1):

After I ran into the issue multiple times myself and couldn't fix it even after re-deploying again (and again...), I found the following worked for me:

- In the deployed version, go to `Content-Type Builder`
- Select the content type that contains the field causing problems
- Click the `Configure the view` button
- Change the position of an arbitrary field
- Click `Save`

This worked for me and also didn't require a re-deployment of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after updating to the 3.6.11 version. Try to remove .cache and build folders and rebuild the app. This worked for me.